# IE 10 issue with new tab

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer

I have come across an issue in IE 10 where I first open the browser by clicking on Internet explorer icon and then login to the web application.Then I right click and select open in new tab option at times it opens in a new window and cookies are lost . I would like to know if this is a known issue in IE 10 and how to address it.